# Processing Android SplitView using Frangments

Tags: android, android-layout, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an app which needs to implement splitview functionality in android. I have created splitview using fragments. When the orientation of screen is portrait the left fragment is hidden and a button 'details' (outside fragment) is shown (in place of left fragment) leaving the right fragment visible as it is. When i click the details button the hidden left splitview should be visible. How to achieve that??

Note that the right fragment is visible throughout the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly you have 2 fragments on the screen right?

Well, so load the buttonFragment on the left(leftFrameLayout?) sameTime as you load the rightFragment on the right(rightFrameLayout).

When you push the button, you detach the buttonFragment and attach the leftFragment to the left(leftFrameLayout)...

I'd guess something like that?

If you are looking for fragment guide, here is a simple one:
[Lars Vogellas fragment guide](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial)

Comment: and how to do that can u demonstrate with some kind of example code??